# Softphone (SIP client) for Windows with note taking capabilities per number

Tags: windows, note-taking, voip

I am looking for a Windows SIP client/softphone that is capable of saving notes per number and bringing up saved notes whenever said number calls again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [tSIP](http://tomeko.net/software/SIPclient/) has option to save text with contact and bring it on incoming and/or outgoing call or manually if you configure "Contact note" button. Local and global hotkeys can be assigned to buttons, so it might be semi-convenient. Personally I would prefer opening note on request than automatically.

It is very, very basic though - just text in ugly window. If you have any kind of CRM software or dedicated software for taking notes that can be interfaced with e.g. command line, opening page in a browser or sending HTTP request it probably could be way more convenient and powerful. tSIP has a dozen of scripting events and configurable buttons to which scripts can be assigned, using e.g. ShellExecute() function.

Comment: This is very good! I don't mind the "ugly" UI at all and the note taking behavior is what I had in mind. There's a CRM but interfacing with it isn't an option at the moment (maybe soon).
One feature I'd really want though is the ability to have many tSIPs write to a single contacts file (stored in the network) or ability to merge multiple contacts files so note can be visible from multiple PCs. Is this possible?

Comment: I've added (http://tomeko.net/tmp/tSIP.exe) options to specify contacts settings file and to check this file timestamp periodically and reload if changed - this might work if number of users is not too big. Each contact can now also have associated file (e.g. text file on shared/network drive) that can be opened manually/automatically (e.g. with Notepad++) - this might be better than note assigned to contact entry.

Comment: This is great, thank you! For now I want to test it with 3-5 users writing to the same file so it'll hopefully work.
Also, not sure if it was there before but can an option be added so that every incoming/outgoing call gets added automatically to the contacts file so notes can be added during/after the call?
(The goal is to track every single call made by briefly writing down what was said.)

Comment: Another option might be using something like Etherpad Lite (collaborative editor), using URLs as files in contact entries. If you have ring group I would still prefer using "Contact file" button or hotkey associated with it in softphone than opening it automatically. I don't know if it is possible to automate adding basic call description (time, direction) to pad page, but it can be simplified by adding to softphone script that would put it in clipboard on request.

Comment: That could help but collaboration isn't as important to me, being able to quickly save a few notes is much more important, which is why I am looking for an option to automatically save the number to contacts and open the notes window.
Is this possible with a script?

Comment: See https://tomeko.net/software/SIPclient/howto/shared_contact_notes.php

Comment: This is a step in the (my) right direction. Since the comments here aren't the right place to have such long discussions I'm gonna open an Issue on GitHub to do it properly.
Thanks for being so helpful!